# JAVA/Jogl/OpenGL displaying 10 bit imageData which is stored in a byte array

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm getting 10 bit Pixels(Grayscale) through USB and store them in a byte array.
So for example the first byte (imgData[0]) contains the first 8 bits of the first pixel. The second byte (imgData[1]) contains the last 2 bits of the first pixel and the first 6 bits of the second pixel, etc...

To get an array where each index represents 1 pixel I stored all the bits from the bytearray into a BitSet and from the BitSet to an Integer array

I've only displayed an 8 bit image as a texture before by creating a byteBuffer:

```
private static ByteBuffer buffer;
```

wrapped it

```
buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imgData);
```

and used

```
gl.glTexImage2D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, 1280, 1024, 0,
                GL2.GL_LUMINANCE, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

if I need to use the 10 bit data now I probably need to use an IntBuffer and could use 32 bit. But I only need 10 bits. How do I scale/tell OpenGl that a value of 1023 means white and a value 0 means black?

Alternatively :

Is there a way I can input the ImgData straight as a ByteArray and OpenGL performs some magic and creates 1 pixel out of each 10 bits that are stored in the ByteArray?
I'v read something about glPixelStore, Pixel packing/unpacking etc. but I couldn't figure out if this really is capable of doing what I need and how to use this.

Comment: I have no clue what openGL is capable of but I'd assume it can't handle anything > 8 bit per channel. You'll probably need to remove those 2 extra bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

OpenGL's [pixel transfer system](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) cannot handle non-byte-aligned pixel data. You can't have an array of 10-bit pixels; every pixel *must* start on a byte boundary.

Furthermore, OpenGL cannot store such pixel data either; there is no `GL_LUMINANCE10` or `GL_R10` [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Formats). You can store it in a `GL_RGB10_A2` format, but that's still a problem, since

The best thing you can do is to pre-process your array of 10-bit pixels, converting each pixel into a 32-bit RGB10_A2 format (replicating the 10-bits, and setting the alpha to full). Then you can upload with a pixel transfer format of GL_RGBA and a pixel transfer type of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2` (or, for performance reasons, probably `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV`). And don't forget about the endian issues of unsigned integers.

Comment: Okay I did that... Thanks to you for the help! But converting from my byte array to an int array is rather time consuming.
So I wanted to give it a new try/approach and managed to receive my data as follows: 
Each Pixel starts on byte boundary now. imgData[0] are the first 8 bits and imgData[1] the last 2 bits. The others are 000000.
Is there a way now to interpret these 2 bytes as one 16 bit color?
I tried   gl.glTexImage2D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_LUMINANCE16, 1280, 1024, 0,
      GL2.GL_LUMINANCE, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
but am doing something wrong as I keep gettin errors